# CsvHelper - How to read header with delimiter inside quotes?

Tags: c#, csv, .net-core

I have troubles reading the .csv header with CsvHelper (https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper, 28.0.1)

Header looks like this:

> DEPOT ID,DEPOT NAME,Open,Close,Open Saturday,Close Saturday,Load (min)
> Fixed,Load (s)/pallet Variable,Unload (min) Fixed,unload s/pallet
> Variable ,House Number,Post Code,Town,"Coordinates, X","Ccoordinates,
> Y",START,UNLOADING allowed

I expect the **"Coordinates, X"** is read as single item, however it is split into two items (because of the comma that is used as delimiter - parameter delimiterUsed):

[image: header]

My CsvConfiguration:

```
public static CsvConfiguration GetCsvConfiguration(string delimiterUsed = null, bool validateHeaders = true, bool hasHeader = false)
        {
            CsvConfiguration readerConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                MissingFieldFound = null,
                PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header?.Trim() ?? "",
                HasHeaderRecord = hasHeader,
            };
          
            if (delimiterUsed != null)
            {
                readerConfig.Delimiter = delimiterUsed;
            }
            else
            {
                readerConfig.DetectDelimiter = true;
                readerConfig.DetectDelimiterValues = new[] { ";", ",", "|", "\t" };
            }

            if (!validateHeaders)
            {
                readerConfig.HeaderValidated = null;
            }

            if (hasHeader) {
                readerConfig.Mode = CsvHelper.CsvMode.RFC4180,
                TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
             }

            return readerConfig;
        }
```

If I debug **PrepareHeaderForMatch** I can see the columns are already wrongly split there, so I cannot perform any change there.

What am I missing?

Update:

I am using *GetRecords()* to get the data by Model - the column are wrong. Is there any chance the PrepareHeaderForMatch is called later than data bind?

```
var records = csv.GetRecords<Model>().ToList();
```

Comment: If you use a comma as the split control then it's clearly gonna be a problem when you have a comma in the middle of a param, you can either work it around (if you have control on the csv generation) by removing the commas between coordinates & X/Y, or change the split value using a TAB or ", if no control on the generation then make a custom control to join those cols

Comment: Csv file is generated by customer. I was hoping somehow to recognize the "quotes around, the column name" -> to not parse the comma inside.